# Getting "stuck" using STM

Tags: haskell, stm

I have the following [Scotty](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/scotty) app which tries to use STM to keep a count of API calls served:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

module Main where

import Web.Scotty
import Data.Monoid (mconcat)
import Control.Concurrent.STM
import Control.Monad.IO.Class

main :: IO ()
main = do
  counter <- newTVarIO 0
  scotty 3000 $
    get "/:word" $ do
      liftIO $ atomically $ do
        counter' <- readTVar counter
        writeTVar counter (counter' + 1)
      liftIO $ do
        counter' <- atomically (readTVar counter)
        print counter'
      beam <- param "word"
      html $ mconcat ["<h1>Scotty, ", beam, " me up!</h1>"]
```

I "load test" the API like this:

```
ab -c 100 -n 100000 http://127.0.0.1:3000/z
```

However, the API serves roughly about 16 thousand requests and then gets "stuck" - `ab` stops with error `apr_socket_recv: Operation timed out (60)`.

I think I'm misusing STM, but not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any suggestions?

Comment: How much CPU is your server using when it gets "stuck"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quick guess here.  16,000 is about the number of available TCP ports.  Is is possible you have not closed any connections and therefore run out of open ports for `ab`?

Comment: yep, that's it! thank you! all those connections are in `TIME_WAIT` state. does this suggest that scotty is not closing connections properly?

Comment: So what's the solution?

Comment: seems like `wrk` (instead of `ab`) doesn't cause this issue.

Comment: @firefrorefiddle, I'm not quite sure. I clicked because I spent a lot of time learning STM, not Scotty. I know that TCP ports need to be closed before more can be opened, but how to make that happen should probably be asked in a new question with Scotty prominently in the title.